# Starting out with reversing

Tags: winapi, reverse-engineering, decompiling

I am just starting to learn reverse engineering..So I am referring the reversing secrets book and binary auditor package. Besides this, can anyone tell me what should I read or refer to if I want to perfect my conversion of assembly into c/c++ (decompilation), even though I only know C and not cpp. I also want to do WinAPI; any reading material besides Forger's tut and also that are short..

Thanks in advance

Comment: This question is too generic as it stands now. You need to be more specific; do you have a specific problem that you're looking for a solution for?

Comment: Nope just need good references for the aforementioned subjects..thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About the reverse engineering: I wan't discourage you by trying to do that, but there are few reasons why you should consider:

- Maybe illegal. Most of the programs which want to share their source codes declare this openly, thence there is a great number of open source - GPL programs around. Commercial, closed-source programs usally won't allow such things as decompilation-disassemblation, or any kind of reverse engineering. So be careful.
- Decompilation is not a trivial issue, as it could seems to be. Reversing a Java bytecode is not so difficult. But when you came across reversing an exe, the things change. Decomplilers such as the [IDA pro](http://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/index.shtml) require an strong user experience and a good amount of "patience" over all.
  Maybe you will succeed to reverse a simple executable code, but with a "fatter" program you'll get in trouble more likely.
- You have to spend lots of time in trying to reverse an executable program.

---

About the C and Winapi material:
I've found a good book the Programming Windows, of Charles Petzold (MS Press), but also the Windows via C-C++ by Jeffrey Richter and Christophe Nasarre, and Windows System Programming, by Johnson M. Hart. 
About free links on the web, i could suggest to you:

[Wikibooks Windows programming](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Windows_Programming)

[This short Win32 API tutorial](http://zetcode.com/gui/winapi/index.html)

[Aleax.it tutorial (in Italian)](http://www.aleax.it/TutWin32/tc.htm)

[The MSDN reference, of course](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/).

Hope it helps!